# android trigger sql syntax error

Tags: java, android, sql, triggers

I have an android app adding values to a highscores db.
Just before an add, i want to create a trigger to delete all but top 10, if it doesnt already exist.
Anyone know what is wrong with this? It says syntax error near 'if'

```
"if exists (select * from sys.triggers where name = 'trig') 
BEGIN CREATE TRIGGER trig AFTER INSERT ON " + DB_TABLE + 
" BEGIN DELETE FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " + COL_NAME + 
" NOT IN (SELECT " + COL_NAME + " FROM " + DB_TABLE + 
" ORDER BY " + COL_SCORE + " DESC LIMIT 10); END; END;";
```

Any ideas would be amazing.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that syntax is valid but according with the documentation you can write:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS trig ....
```

Take a look here:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html